# How do I pass DbContext using Unity DI?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unity-container

I am using latest version of **MVC**, **EF** & **Unity**.

```
 public interface IUnitOfWork
    {
        IGenericRepository<Topic> TopicRepository { get; }
        bool Commit();
    }
```

Below is my `IUnitOfWork`:

```
  public class UnitOfWork : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
    {

        private GenericRepository<Topic> _topicRepository;
        private DbSet<Topic> Topics { get; set; }


        public IGenericRepository<Topic> TopicRepository
        {
            get { return _topicRepository ?? (_topicRepository = new GenericRepository<Topic>(Topics)); }
        }
        public bool Commit()
        {
            this.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
    }

...

public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
        IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        T Single(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        T SingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        T First(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        T GetById(int id);
        void Add(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);

    }

... 

public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
    {

        private readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;
        public GenericRepository(DbSet<T> dbSet)
        {
            this._dbSet = dbSet;
        }
        public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return _dbSet;
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return this._dbSet.Where(predicate);
        }

        public T Single(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return this._dbSet.Where(predicate).Single();
        }

        public T SingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return this._dbSet.Where(predicate).SingleOrDefault();
        }

        public T First(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return this._dbSet.Where(predicate).First();
        }

        public T GetById(int id)
        {
            return this._dbSet.Find(id);
        }

        public void Add(T entity)
        {
            _dbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        public void Delete(T entity)
        {
            _dbSet.Remove(entity);
        }
    }

...
```

`UnityConfig.cs`:

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            // NOTE: To load from web.config uncomment the line below. Make sure to add a Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration to the using statements.
            // container.LoadConfiguration();

            // TODO: Register your types here
            // container.RegisterType<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
            container.RegisterType<DbContext>();
            //container.RegisterType<DbContext, MFRContext>(); 
            container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
        }

...
```

In my `HomeController`, I have this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        private UnitOfWork _uow;
        public ActionResult Index(UnitOfWork uow)
        {
            _uow = uow;

            _uow.TopicRepository.Add(new Topic { Title = "Title 1", Post = "Post 2", CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, CreatedBy = "Ad" });

            _uow.TopicRepository.GetAll();


            return View();
        }
}
```

1. In which class `DbContext` should be injected ?
2. How do configure Unity for `IUnitOfWork` to be injected in `HomeController` ?

Comment: Typically constructor injection is used for injecting a context into a controller.

Comment: Why would you have DbContext in controller  ?? I have UoW defined for that.

Comment: still amounts to the same thing -- you have a dependency you want to inject.  You probably will use constructor injection.  It is not so important whether it is the context itself or your UOW with its own context reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try injecting unit of work in constructor:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private UnitOfWork _uow;

    public HomeController(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        _uow.TopicRepository.Add(new Topic { Title = "Title 1", Post = "Post 2", CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, CreatedBy = "Ad" });

        _uow.TopicRepository.GetAll();


        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: In which layer should my EF DBContext go ? After i need to connect to DB to save data.

Comment: @Nexus: What do you mean? DbContext in Your code is part of unit of work and it handles database connection.